# Drawing a transparent NSView in NSWindow with black background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a `NSView` inside a `NSWindow` and the background of `NSWindow` is set to black (with alpha of 0.7). Is there anyway to have the `NSView` showing what's underneath the `NSWindow`? In other words, how do I make the part where `NSWindow` and `NSView` overlap to have clear background?

Thanks!

Comment: So what do you want to see in the overlapped area? The black ground colour of the NSWindow?

Comment: Basically the desktop area behind NSWindow. I want that part of NSWindow to have a clear background too.

Comment: It is the confusing part: if you says 'desktop area' behind NSWindow, do you mean you want to see the part of desktop wallpaper covered by NSWindow?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I want to see the desktop wallpaper covered by NSWindow at the location where NSView is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [setOpaque](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setOpaque%3a) method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, it seems like you're trying to have a window with hole in it. You can take a look at apple's sample code [Round Transparent Window](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000401-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). It shows how to add transparent areas to an NSWindow.